# Releasing an unfinished Android app?

Tags: development-process, android, applications, release

I plan to release my very first app on Google Play Store but I am still a bit confused on the concept of releasing software. I tried to read a few articles online about the life cycle of software development but it left me with more questions.

My Question is: Can I and should I release my app if it has a lot of unfinished parts? 
Because doing so will help me get my audience and see their feedback. In addition, I would also get ownership or rights for my app.

Answer (score 7):

### You only get one chance to make a first impression.

If you release an obviously unfinished buggy app, the first people to look at it will drown you in negative reviews.

Once you have a lot of negative reviews on an app, no one will look at it - even if you claim to have fixed the bugs and finished the app.

Leave out as many features as you can (i.e., if you don't yet support taking photos in your app, *don't put a camera button on the user interface*)

Comment: Case in point: No Man's Sky.

Comment: Jeeze if you sell as many copies as no mans sky you wont care if people like it

Answer (score 3):

Don't pollute the app store with unfinished crap.

People who download your app are your customers, not your beta testers. They are not part of the development team.

If the app is of no real use, don't waste people's time.

That's not to say that you need all features available in 1.0. Shipping is also a feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test your application try beta testing feature in Google play. Users can still download your app but it won't affect your reputation because it's a beta product.
Don't release unfinished product.
Users don't care about developer efforts they need perfect working apps. Otherwise your account will be flooded with bad reviews and ratings.